# Is it possible to update a password on an account with an expired password with only the keytab?

Tags: kerberos

Let's say I have the keytab file to one of my accounts, and it was generated using the last good password to my account. If the password has expired, when attempting to `kinit` with the keytab, it results in `kinit: Password has expired while getting initial credentials`.

Now attempting to kinit without the keytab does prompt for the old password, which will then ask for a new password to be entered. However, I'd like my service to essentially be able to 'throw away' the password without storing it, but it has to be resilient to the password expiring. As far as I can tell, this is just not a supported scenario in kerberos.

Is there anyway to accomplish resetting an expired password with just the keytab?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. Keytabs contains set of keys and are equivalent of passwords.

According to the doc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27515_01/common/tutorials/kerberos_keytab.html#:%7E:text=The%20purpose%20of%20the%20Keytab,passwords%20or%20for%20human%20intervention.),

> The Kerberos Keytab file contains mappings between Kerberos Principal
> names and DES-encrypted keys that are derived from the password used
> to log into the Kerberos Key Distribution Center (KDC). The purpose of
> the Keytab file is to allow the user to access distinct Kerberos
> Services without being prompted for a password at each Service.

The kinit program decrypts the TGT using the user's key- which is present in keytab, or prompted if keytab is not provided. 
The client uses the TGT to request a ticket for the service from the Ticket Granting Service (TGS), which runs on the KDC. 
Obviously, if the keys in keytabs are expired, there is no way kinit can decrypt the user's TGT. And without TGT, there is no way to perform any AD operations including updating the password.

A keytab file is generally generated for service users, not the end user.
General guideline is to enable the settings - 1) *Password never expires* 2) *User can not change his own password*